# Finding parent for William Jefferson KLJG-CYG who was born District of Columbia about 1810?

Tags: united-states, birth-records, virginia, 1800s-decade, 1810s

I have looked for 2 years and can't seem to find a parent for:

William Jefferson
Birth:  About 1810 District of Columbia, United States
Death:  1890 Alexandria, Virginia

I can find several censuses for him, but no birth or death records.  I am unable to continue my family tree with out this information.  My grandmother thought that his father's name was John.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites.  To attract potential answerers to your question perhaps you can include more details (preferably with sources) to the events you have uncovered for William after his birth.  Do any of those refer to any siblings for him?